# Pass a custom object list to an activity: parcelable or serializable?

Tags: android

From android documentation:

> NOTE: Seeing Parcelable might have triggered the question, why is Android not using the built-in Java serialization mechanism? It turns out that the Android team came to the conclusion that the serialization in Java is far too slow to satisfy Android’s interprocess-communication requirements. So the team built the Parcelable solution. The Parcelable approach requires that you explicitly serialize the members of your class, but in the end, you get a much faster serialization of your objects.

**So we know that Parcelable is actually better than Serializable** but, on the other hand,

> Also realize that Android provides two mechanisms that allow you to pass data to another process. The first is to pass a bundle to an activity using an intent, and the second is to pass a Parcelable to a service. These two mechanisms are not interchangeable and should not be confused. That is, the Parcelable is not meant to be passed to an activity. **If you want to start an activity and pass it some data, use a bundle. Parcelable is meant to be used only as part of an AIDL definition**.

**Ok man, but I need to pass a custom object list to my activity!So into the bundle I still have to put either a parcelable or a serializable!**

For now I did this way:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable{
```

and to pass:

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putSerializable("objList", anArrayListWithMyObjectElements);
 intent.putExtra("objList", b);
```

as ArrayList implements Serializable too it works fine...but I don't see the point of using a bundle this way...but android tells me to not use Parcelable for activity communication...what's the correct answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my exprience, I strongly suggest using `Parcelable` when you can, IPC or not. It's Android's *de facto* replacement for Java's `Serializable`, and it's more optimized.

If you need help on how to parcel an object, let me know.

Comment: I though making this way: 1)I let my custom object implement Parcelable (it has a lot of simple attributes), than I make a container class which still implements Parcelable and contains an ArrayList of these objects: its parcelable implementation just calls parcelable methods for each object...is it correct?

Comment: Parcelable is the best approach.

Comment: Serializable is much more simplier than parcelable. There is a lot of cases where serializable is just enough and parcelable's advantages doesn't kick.

Comment: `ArrayList` implements `Parcelable` so you don't need any wrapper class actually.

Comment: I came across with situations where unmarshalling simply fails. I don't know why. So, I have to use Serializable rather than Parcelable. Classes are much more simpler, no issue with speed.